# Windows Batch Script: Find the name of the last folder in the directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, find

I'm writing a batch file to copy the contents of a folder to a folder in the same directory with a new name. I want the naming convention to be:
2021000-Template  (this is where the files are copied from)
2021001-CompanyA
2021002-CompanyB
etc

I'm prompting for the company name but am stuck at this last part.

How do I find the name of the last folder in the directory, store the 202100x in a variable and add 1 to it?

Afterwards I will need to include the new variable in the string with cname but i think I can figure that out.

Thanks for your help!

```
@echo off
:: CD to correct folder and year in the root
CD\Estimates\2021 

:: Asks for user input on company name and stores it in the cname var
Set /P "cname= Enter Company Name (without spaces): "

:: Copying the entire contents of the Template folder to a new folder named the cname
XCOPY C:\Estimates\2021\2021000-Template C:\Estimates\2021\%cname% /S /I

:: Opens the new folder
start C:\Estimates\2021\%cname%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on C:\Estimates\2021\2021*-*') do set /a last=%%a+1
echo next subdirectory to be created is "%last% - %cname%"
```

should do the job, assuming there's no subdirectorynames that start `2021` and have a `-` in their name that does not follow your pattern.

The `dir` command produces a list in basic form (name only) of directories (`/ad`) in name-order (`/on`) that match the pattern "2021`something`-`somethingelse`". The `tokens=1` (which is implicit) selects the first token in each directoryname in turn, delimited by the `-` so `%%a` will be assigned `2021000` , `2021001` , `2021002`  and so on - in that order. The `set /a` adds 1 to the number so is the next number in the sequence. In this way, the next number available is selected when the `for` loop ends, even if numbers have for some reason been deleted.